# ColumnTransformer with more than 3 columns

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence

Can someone help me with the below one?

```
X:
[500 5 1 405 4 1120 505 0]
...
[525 5 1 127 4 2135 223 0] 
[470 1 3 121 6 1555 318 0] 
[580 2 1 108 6 1525 120 0] 
[540 4 3 112 1 425  209 2] 
[510 1 1 113 6 1525 122 0]
...
```

This one works.

```
encoder = OneHotEncoder(categories='auto', drop = 'first')
columntransformer = ColumnTransformer([("encoder_1", encoder, [1,2,4])], remainder = 'passthrough')
X = columntransformer.fit_transform(X).astype(float)
```

But with 4 columns it doesn't:

```
encoder = OneHotEncoder(categories='auto', drop = 'first')
columntransformer = ColumnTransformer([("encoder_1", encoder, [1,2,4,7])], remainder = 'passthrough')
X = columntransformer.fit_transform(X).astype(float)
```

Comment: Are you getting an error or is the transformation not happening?

Comment: The variable X is getting removed from the memory once I do the fit_transform with 4 columns.

Comment: Actually I'm getting this: X = <228x28 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
 with 1593 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>

Comment: That is expected the output of the function, if any of the transformations result in a sparse matrix, then the full output will be a sparse matrix (due to the concatenation). What you are looking to obtain out of the transformation?

Comment: sc = StandardScaler()
X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train) once I do this I'm getting this error: "Cannot center sparse matrices: pass `with_mean=False` "

ValueError: Cannot center sparse matrices: pass `with_mean=False` instead. See docstring for motivation and alternatives.

Comment: Please post a full, runnable, minimal example we can use to duplicate this.  Also please add the error you are seeing to the question and not just leave it as a comment.